CSS max width vs fondo blanco
Os expongo mi problema:
Estoy tratando de maquetar una web para la universidad con HTML y CSS y estoy atascado con algo a lo que no le encuentro una explicación.
La cosa es que tengo un <main> el cual tiene 3 <section> en su interior.
La <section> de en medio, tiene como fondo el fondo que le he puesto al <body> que se trata de una imagen de frambuesas. Por otro lado, tanto la primera como la tercera <section> tienen un fondo blanco.
Para ello, he tratado de poner divs llamados "white-background-box" con un 100% de width que engloban a la primera y tercera section o divs (digo section o divs porque he quitado y puesto divs por todas partes, dentro de la section, fuera englobando todo el section, etc. Y nada funciona).
La cosa es que tengo otra clase llamada "container" que establece un maxwidth y esta clase solo la aplico a los divs dentro del section que quiero que su contenido se ciña a este tamaño, pero tiene un div padre con un width del 100% para que coja todo el ancho de pantalla y establezca el fondo de color blanco pero no hay forma de hacerlo.
Esto es lo que quiero:

pero, esto es lo que tengo:

No hay forma de hacer que el div del primero y el tercero ocupe todo el ancho de pantalla para hacer el fondo blanco aunque a estos no le aplique la clase container con el maxwidth

La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Para que las secciones ocupen el 100% del ancho del body, puedes establecerle a este (al body) un margen de 0.
Eso hará que automáticamente las secciones ocupen todo el ancho.
Lo siguiente es establecer a las secciones de tu interés un color de fondo blanco.
Dejo un ejemplo usando la estructura que has descrito en la pregunta.


body {
  background-image: url(https://i.sstatic.net/eAY52kYv.png);
  background-size:cover;
  margin: 0px;
}

section {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blanco {
  background-color: white;
}
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Mi título</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="blanco">
      Contenido de la primera sección
    </section>
    <section>
      Contenido de la segunda sección
    </section>
    <section class="blanco">
      Contenido de la tercera sección
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Contenido del pie de página
  <footer>
</body>




Gracias! la verdad es que justo antes de que comentases he resuelto el problema de otro modo.
Me he ido a la etiqueta  y le he puesto un width del 100%, esto ha resuelto el problema con solo ese atributo!
